# unit test rabbitMQ c# Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rabbitmq, moq

I´m trying to unit test my RabbitMQ exchanges and queues, using the Moq nuget package. but no matter how I try and how much I use google, I cannot understand how I am supposed to mock rabbitMQ objects. 
any pointers to someone very new to unit test, mockups???

I have tried using the nuget package RabbitMQ.Fakes like so:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void testconnectionnotnull()
{
    FakeConnectionFactory factory = new FakeConnectionFactory();
    IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();

    NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(connection.IsOpen);
    NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(factory.Connection, 
    NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreSame(connection));
}
```

but when I create the `IConnection`, I get following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'CreateBasicPublishBatch' of type 'RabbitMQ.Fakes.FakeModel' from assembly 'RabbitMQ.Fakes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not implemented.'

I´ve also tried just to instantiate a standard mock object, but I cannot find the right way to do so and be able to use it.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestFactoryNotNull()
{
    Mock<Rabbit_Recieve> mock = new Mock<Rabbit_Recieve>(); 
}
```

Comment: post your code ... what you have tried and specific part where you are stuck

Comment: ofcourse, I have deleted all of my attempts (trying to follow something else, only to find I could not use it) 
but I have tried to recreate my errors again, and post is updated now

Comment: What are you actually trying to test? Typically there are not a lot of valid unit test cases that depend on the message broker.

Comment: unit testing is not my strong suit, so honestly... I´m not sure of what I´m trying to test. 
it's part of a school project, where we have been told to incoorperate unit tests of our different parts of software. 

I was thinking, maybe making sure that there is a n open connection, and other basics. 

I do have a case, where, if I have a specified amount of calls in my queue, I need to instantiate a new instance of our microservice.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to test RabbitMQ code is to write isolated unit tests for your *consumer*.

That is, your consumer should essentially be just a function which receives a message. So your unit tests should just create a mock rabbit message and then call the consumer with that message and then you check that the consumer does what you expect it to. In other words, the consumer should be decoupled from the Rabbit code.

You shouldn't really have to test the rabbit connection etc because that is part of the rabbit library.